# Odoo10 ProgrammingError: column id does not exist in pivot-table

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, odoo, odoo-10

When clicking menu for open the pivot view, I keep encountering the error "ProgrammingError: column new_table_report.id does not exist".

My code file .py:

```py
@api.model_cr
def init(self):
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'new_table_report')
    self._cr.execute("""
          CREATE or REPLACE VIEW new_table_report AS (
              SELECT  sub.*, 
                      (SELECT name FROM maintenance_rating_score_range WHERE 
                         (sub.average_deviation >= from_score and 
                          sub.average_deviation <= to_score)
                       ) as rating
              FROM(
                   SELECT  
                      eq.id as equipment_id,
                      eq.name as name,
                      eq.category_id as category_id,
                      eq.partner_id as partner_id,
                      count(m.id) as number_service,
                      (sum(rs.score)/count(m.id)) as average_deviation
                   FROM maintenance_request m
                     INNER JOIN maintenance_equipment eq on (m.equipment_id = eq.id)
                     INNER JOIN maintenance_rating r on (r.request_id = m.id)
                     LEFT JOIN maintenance_rating_score rs on (r.rating_satisf_id = rs.id)
                  GROUP BY eq.id, eq.partner_id
              )AS sub 
         )
    """)
```

My code file .xml:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_new_table_report_pivot">
    <field name="name">new.table.report.pivot</field>
    <field name="model">new.table.report</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <pivot string="Report Analysis" disable_linking="False">
            <field name="equipment_id" type="row"/>
            <field name="number_service" type="measure"/>
            <field name="average_deviation" type="measure"/>
        </pivot>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_new_tabke_report">
    <field name="name">Report Analysis</field>
    <field name="res_model">new.table.report</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">pivot,graph</field>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
</record>
```

Thank you for Advance.

Answer (score -2):

I can do it, i don't create id field in new table report

Comment: Could you please answer in a more detailed way? What did you forget in the query and add your new fixed code.